# VS2010 C# website development process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, .net-4.0, crystal-reports, windows-7-x64

I'm developing a ASP.NET 4 C# web application in VS2010 Professional on Windows 7 Professional x64.

When I'm debugging with my localhost and I make changes to the .cs file and save(ctrl-s), a save-as dialog pops up and when I click "Yes" to "[...] already exists. Do you want to replace it?" I get the following error: "The process cannot access the file[...]because it is being used by another process" (despite being able to save while debugging for the last 2 years).

When I stop debugging the same behavior exists. I try to delete the .cs file in its directory and I get the following error: "This action can't be completed because the file is open in Microsoft Visual Studio 2010"

It takes perhaps 5 minutes after having stopped debugging so finally be able to save the file.

Differences from other projects:

- A whole list of windows updates including a security update to .net 4 (KB2789642)
- Installation of crystal reports 7 on my development environment.
- Inclusion of crystal reports assemblies in my web.config.

I've tried using Unlocker and the behavior still persists.

Answer (score 0):

It's strange, and perhaps someone can provide a better answer, but sometimes VS gets in a situation where it cannot access files that it has locked itself. The only solution I've found is to reboot visual studio. Sorry I can't be more help.

Comment: I appreciate your input. I noticed this first occurring 4 days ago, rebooting visual studio and my computer doesn't eliminate the behavior. Thank you though.